# How to add Toolbar Button for Firefox Australis

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I used below code to add toolbar buttons automatically in navigation toolbar below Firefox Australis.

```
var buttonId =  "toolbarbutton-toolbarbutton";
var navBar = document.getElementById("nav-bar");
var currentSet = navBar.currentSet;

var curSet = currentSet.split(",");
if (curSet.indexOf(buttonId) == -1)
{
    navBar.insertItem(buttonId);
    navBar.setAttribute("currentset", navBar.currentSet);
    document.persist("nav-bar", "currentset");

    try
    {
        top.BrowserToolboxCustomizeDone(true);
    }
    catch (e)
    {

    }
}
```

Because user interface and modules changed for Australis, the code needs to be updated. How can I add Toolbar Button for Australis proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [`CustomizableUI` module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/CustomizableUI.jsm):

```js
try
{
  Components.utils.import("resource:///modules/CustomizableUI.jsm");
  CustomizableUI.createWidget({
    id: "toolbarbutton-toolbarbutton",
    defaultArea: "nav-bar",
    removable: true,
    label: "My button",
    tooltiptext: "My tooltip text",
    onClick: function()
    {
      alert("Clicked");
    }
  });
}
catch (e)
{
  Components.utils.reportError(e);

  // No such module? Try the old approach.
  ...
}
```

Note that the widget no longer needs to be added for each browser window, it is enough to do it once. Unfortunately, the module documentation is practically non-existent right now, the code above has been deduced from [module's source code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/customizableui/src/CustomizableUI.jsm). The documentation should improve soon however.

If it helps, Adblock Plus source code contains an [emulation of the CustomizableUI API](https://hg.adblockplus.org/adblockplus/file/cdecc6838c02/lib/customizableUI.js) for older Firefox versions. This one is far from complete however, it is only meant to cover the needs of Adblock Plus.

Comment: great but I can not add button after I remove it from navigation toolbar by `removeWidgetFromArea(id)` . Can I toggle button if possible?

Comment: @Xunshirine: You use `addWidgetToArea(id, area, position)` method (you have to remember the position yourself).